# Mailgun setup with Laravel 5

Tags: email, laravel-5, configuration, mailgun

When we are configuring email with mail gun account with our domain name .In `.env` file what does it mean `MAIL_USERNAME` ?? is it the email address or SMTP login name from mail gun account. ?

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*******
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

In my `.env` file i have added `MAIL_Username` as `postmaster@domain.com` which i have gotten from mail gun account ? is this correct way of doing ?can anyone confirm on this ?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is the correct way.

mine looks like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mg@mail.domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="this-is-my-secret"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: that email id should be with the domain name or it can be any gmail ? @Rene

Comment: But my emails are going to spam ..why ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: okay, real code example:
I send mails from 'velka@mail.ceoninternet.dk' and my mail username is xxx@mail.ceoninternet.dk.

But if i tried to send a mail from a different domain (velka@velka.dk) or when i set a different return adresse, than the domain it is send from, it goes to spam.

Comment: @RenéJuulAskjær : some how i fixed it but still mails are going to junk for some email ids. i have no clue how to fix it ?